# Regex: exclude digits with two dots

Tags: regex, perl

Could you please explain me, why Perl regex

```
$text = 150 45.5 678,68767 15.10.14;
$text =~ m/[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+[^.]/;
```

captures
 
**150 
45.5 
678,68767 
15.10
14**?
I'd like to exclude 15.10.14 and thats why I added **[^.]** but it works not as I expected...
I guess that expression have been interpreted as:
[0-9]+ => 15.1
[^.] => 0
but I have no idea how to rewrite it to get only numbers with one **.** or **,** and exclude dates with two **.**. Could you please help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your explanation of the match is correct.  For a regex, it is imperative to find a match any way possible, so the regex engine will *give back* characters from `[0-9]+` to try and get a match for `[^.]`.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my $text = '150 45.5 678,68767 15.10.14';

my @words = split " ", $text;

for my $word (@words) {
    my $dot_count = () = $word =~ /[.]/gxms;  # `goatse` operator

    if($dot_count < 2) {
        say $word;
    }
}

--output:--
150
45.5
678,68767
```

Or, this works, too:

```
while ($text =~ /([^ ]+)/gxms) { 
    my $word = $1;
    my $dot_count = () = $word =~ /[.]/gxms;

    if($dot_count < 2) {
        say $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `/x`, `/m` and `/s` on your regex are superfluous, and the usual way of counting characters in a string is `my $dot_count = $word =~ tr/.//`

Comment: I am aware that *some* people do that, yes, but in my opinion it is bad practice, in the same way as any other program construct that is written without a purpose. And please try what I suggested with `tr/.//`, or did you really write your code that way so that you could say “goatse operator” and giggle a little? Also take a look at [`perlfaq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string?)

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to @Borodin, your solution works. I hoped that it could be solved with regex only, but I see nothing criminal in some additional lines of code :)

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression matches the 15.10 due to a backtrack because of the `[^.]`

The reason why it matches 15.10 in 15.10.14 is:

```
[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+[^.]
  ^Matches the 15

[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+[^.]
        ^Matches the .

[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+[^.]
             ^Matches the 10

[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+[^.]
                   ^ Causes the backtracking because of the . at position .14

Backtracking switches to see 15.

[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+[^.]
             ^ Now matches the 1

[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+[^.]
                  ^ Now matches the 0
```

Match found!

You can use a atomic group:

```
(?>[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+)[^.]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to match the valid numbers.

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?(?!\S)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oC9wJ9/1)

[EXPLANATION](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3C!%5CS%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%28%3F!%5CS%29)

OR

```
(?<!\S)(?!\d+\.\d+\.)[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+(?!\S)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oC9wJ9/2)